# Why is animating scale and translate with css variable treated differently?

Tags: css, css-animations, css-variables

I'm trying to suss out the differences between the following cases--specifically why scale is preserved in the second div, but not the first.

Secondly why the similar code doesn't work for translate between the third and fourth divs.

(And, if that wasn't cryptic enough, why you have to reverse the animations in the first and third divs to make them run the correct direction).

**Just Click on Each Div to Start Animations**

```css
#div1,#div2,#div3,#div4{position:absolute;height:40px;width:40px;background:orange}
#div2{background:blue;top:100px}
#div3{background:green;top:200px}
#div4{background:purple;top:300px}
@-webkit-keyframes scaleTest {
  0%{-webkit-transform:scale(var(--trnsS,1))}
  100%{--trnsS:2}
}
.scaleTest {-webkit-animation:scaleTest reverse forwards linear 5s}

@-webkit-keyframes otherScaleTest {
  0%{-webkit-transform:scale(var(--trnsS,1))}
  100%{-webkit-transform:scale(var(--trnsS,2))}
}
.otherScaleTest {-webkit-animation:otherScaleTest forwards linear 5s}

@-webkit-keyframes translateTest {
  0%{-webkit-transform:translate3d(var(--trnsx,0px),var(--trnsy,0px),0px)}
  100%{--trnsx:200px}
}
.translateTest {-webkit-animation:translateTest reverse forwards linear 5s}

@-webkit-keyframes otherTranslateTest {
  0%{-webkit-transform:translate3d(var(--trnsx,0px),var(--trnsy,0px),0px)}
  100%{-webkit-transform:translate3d(var(--trnsx,200px),--transy,0px)}
}
.otherTranslateTest {-webkit-animation:otherTranslateTest reverse forwards linear 5s}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="div1" onclick="javascript:this.className='scaleTest'"></div>
  <div id="div2" onclick="javascript:this.className='otherScaleTest'"></div>
    <div id="div3" onclick="javascript:this.className='translateTest'"></div>
  <div id="div4" onclick="javascript:this.className='otherTranslateTest'"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm only targeting the Webkit rendering engine, so I'm viewing the sample code in Chrome/Chromium.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: I don't understand why you are using CSS variables without values. And you're not even declaring them in your divs CSS.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**

Animating scale and translate with CSS variable is **not** treated differently. There were some issues in your CSS that caused your animations to not work properly.

**Explanations**

- To forward the values of the properties, they need to be present in the `100%{…}` (or `0%{…}` if reversed)
- In the 4th `div`, in your `otherTranslateTest`, you used a new variable `--transy` (must be a typo-error for `--trnsy` !) without even using `var(…)`. That caused the animation to not work at all. I've changed it to `var(--trnsy, 0px)` to make it work.
- You don't *need* to reverse the animations. The above corrected your *cryptic* behaviours.

⋅⋅⋅

I've also added the below in the snippet to make it simpler (no need to re-run to re-play the animation) and more visual:

```
function toggle(name){
  event.target.classList.toggle(name);
}

div[class*="Test"] {
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}
```

**Working snippet**

```js
function toggle(name) {
  event.target.classList.toggle(name);
}
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}

div[class*="Test"] {
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}

#div1 {
  background: orange;
}

#div2 {
  background: blue;
  top: 100px;
}

#div3 {
  background: green;
  top: 200px;
}

#div4 {
  background: purple;
  top: 300px;
}


/* Animation of div1 */

@keyframes scaleTest {
  0% {
    transform: scale(var(--trnsS, 1));
    --trnsS: 2; /* Added to work with forwards */
  }
  100% {
    --trnsS: 2;
  }
}

.scaleTest {
  animation: scaleTest reverse forwards linear 5s;
}


/* Animation of div2 */
/* Why using an empty CSS var ? */

@keyframes otherScaleTest {
  0% {
    transform: scale(var(--trnsS, 1)); 
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(var(--trnsS, 2));
  }
}

.otherScaleTest {
  animation: otherScaleTest forwards linear 5s;
}


/* Animation of div3 */

@keyframes translateTest {
  100% {
    --trnsx: 200px;
  }
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(var(--trnsx, 0px), var(--trnsy, 0px), 0px);
    --trnsx: 200px; /* Added to work with forwards */
  }
}

.translateTest {
  animation: translateTest reverse forwards linear 5s;
}


/* Animation of div4 */

@keyframes otherTranslateTest {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(var(--trnsx, 0px), var(--trnsy, 0px), 0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(var(--trnsx, 200px), var(--trnsy, 0px), 0px);
  }
}

.otherTranslateTest {
  animation: otherTranslateTest forwards linear 5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" onclick="toggle('scaleTest');"></div>
<div id="div2" onclick="toggle('otherScaleTest');"></div>
<div id="div3" onclick="toggle('translateTest');"></div>
<div id="div4" onclick="toggle('otherTranslateTest');"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, that would have been a typo, and it took a second set of eyes to find it. Thanks for responding. I'll look through snippet and grok everything said.